# Font text changes size on mouseclick in TextField javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, fonts, scenebuilder

I am facing a problem with javafx TextField. I created my TextField using scene builder and the following code was generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane fx:id="placeHolder" styleClass="pane-with-border" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <HBox prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="1203.0">
      <children>
        <TextArea fx:id="resultDisplay" editable="false" prefHeight="154.0" prefWidth="1224.0" styleClass="result-display">
            <font>
               <Font size="16.0" />
            </font></TextArea>
      </children>
   </HBox>
</StackPane>
```

I am using this TextField to display results. Hence, I set it to be non-editable.  However, once the results have be displayed in this TextField and I click on it, the font-size decreases (as shown below).

[image: small-size-font]

When I click on other components in the window, the font-size reverts back to its original size (and the cycle continues).

[image: normal-size-font]

I have checked my code for any mouse listener events but couldn't find any. So it is not plausible that a mouse event could have caused this problem.

If there is a need to see the actual application and code, my gradle project can be
found [here](https://github.com/lancehaoh/addressbook-level4).

Could someone please advise me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you adding/removing any style classes or pseudo-classes? Do you have any CSS rules which rely on the selected and/or focused pseudo classes?

Comment: @sillyfly I didn't quite get what you mean. As far as I know, there are no other CSS rules that define the style of this text field other than the ones that are defined in the code that I have posted in my question.